# Embed playlist in an Android app?

Tags: android, api, mobile, sdk

We're currently developing a mobile app for our business, which includes a music player. We would like to *embed* our **Soundcloud** playlist but we have issues as there only is a *SDK* for *iOS* but not *Android*

What would be a workaround for this ?

Thanks for your help,
Antoine

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Java Wrapper](https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/java-api-wrapper) for the Soundcloud API you can use ([Github](https://github.com/soundcloud/java-api-wrapper)). It is no longer maintained but it works.

Comment: OK thanks, if it works even without being maintained, we can have a look and see ... It's too bad there's only a SDK for iOS :(

Any news on having this for Android too, maybe ?

Comment: I really don't know. At the moment they have this API for android that's limited to sharing functionality. Maybe they'll extend it one day.